# Create a mathematical problem with randomized parameters

Tags: assessment, online-instruction

Recently I am using [Moodle](https://moodle.org) to create problems with randomized parameters. In Moodle, there is so-called Calculated questions that let me do this in a straightforward way. For example, I can simply type: "Evaluate `$$\int_{{a}}^{{b}}(x^{2}+{c}x+{d})dx$$`" for which the output is something like: "Evaluate
$$\int_{2}^{7}(x^{2}-4x+3)dx.\text{"}$$
Here the numbers $2,7,-4,3$ are generated randomly by Moodle. Thus each student would receive a different problem. Of course, Moodle also allows me to input the answer for this problem: `(-2*pow({a},3) - 3*pow({a},2)*{c} - 6*{a}*{d} + {b}*(2*pow({b},2) + 3*{b}*{c} + 6*{d}))/6` so that the students can check their work right after they type down the answer and I can also assess the student's work automatically.

However, Moodle only allows me to set *one output value* for each problem. For example, I would like to create a problem having several outputs, like: "Let $f(x)=x^{2}+\sqrt{9-x^{2}}+7$. The greatest integer number in the domain of $f$ is $\boxed{\text{a blank box to type the answer here}}$ and the greatest integer number in the range of $f$ is $\boxed{\text{a blank box to type the answer here}}$". Here the numbers $9$ and $7$ are also generated randomly.

I do not know how to do this in Moodle. Note that in Moodle there is so-called *Embedded answers (Cloze) question* that allows multiple outputs, however it does not allow randomized parameters.

**My question**: How do we create a question like in the above example *with randomized parameters* and *several outputs* for which we are also able to *assess* the student's work automatically?

For this, I mean that we can use any platform (not necessarily Moodle). Doing a research I found that we may use some PHP codes to do this in Moodle, see  [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiooLe-6NLrAhXVeisKHbDpAwcQFjAGegQIBxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.exeter.ac.uk%2Fonlineassessment%2Ffiles%2F2012%2F07%2FExamples-of-Mathematics-Eassessment-in-Moodle.docx&usg=AOvVaw1_hVNsUsVD3ouAV7-R2aJd). But I haven't got this work on my own, probably due  to a lack of PHP experience (I think with some suggestions it would be alright). Another way is to install a plugin from [Wiris](http://www.wiris.com/en), however I am not authorised to do this on my Moodle system.

Comment: You might check out [this recent question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18629/do-you-know-of-any-third-party-math-friendly-testing-software).

Comment: @Nick I would definitely check it out.

Comment: @Nick C Hi, what is a practicle way to input math formulas in Myopenmath? For example, I did't see the symbol $\iint$ in the editor. How do we type the double integral symbol?

Comment: If you have an account, there is a lively forum called “How Do I...” where other MOM users (and MOM creator David Lippman) answer questions like this. [It should be part of the support course you are added to you automatically when you start an account.]

Comment: That said, I think it’s just int int, or possibly iint.

Comment: @Nick C There is no search bar there. I would need to open a new (probably old) question.

Comment: I would recommend just starting a new thread with that question. Folks there don’t seem to mind if the question has been asked before.

Comment: @Nick. Thank a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112760/discussion-between-nick-c-and-john).